# Read from command line

Tags: c#, file, command-line, arguments

I have a problem with reading dates. Task:

The goal is to write a program capable of constructing and printing a Huffman tree for a specific file. The program will receive the name of the file in the form of a single command-line argument, read all data from the input file and build the Huffman tree for this file...

Example:

```
$>program.exe simple.in
```

My solution:

```
string FileName = Console.ReadLine();
fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);
```

But this solution writes:

> RE:Runtime error 102: Dereferencing null value

Thanks

Comment: The command line arguments are passed to the `Main` function through the `args[]` parameter.

Comment: So, how should I solve it? Dont understand your answer.

Comment: `string filename = args[0]`? This is assuming your main function looks like: `private static void Main(string[] args)`, and the code is in that method.

Comment: Go to google.com and type: c# command line arguments

Comment: I still have absolutely zero idea what this has to do with dates.

Comment: data from file: simple.in

Comment: `Console.ReadLine` gets input from the user at runtime, not from the command line.

Comment: and what does mean $>program.exe?

Comment: SO is not a tutorial site. There are some very basic fundamentals that you're missing. Please read a book or at least go through some online tutorials before jumping into completing challenges.

Comment: @RufusL in my computer it works, but if I upload to school server, it shows that error

Comment: @itsme86 your help=0, im not begginer

Comment: @FandaKožnar You haven't presented enough of a code sample or description of the repro steps for anyone to help. You say you want to read from the command line, yet you're reading from the console. But then you say it works on your machine but not at school. It's not clear exactly what you want. People are suggesting tutorials because your question sounds like a beginner. Please add details if you want a better answer.

Comment: Not a single thing you've presented to us makes me think you're not a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. 
Instead of:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

I used:

```
args[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started for reading from the command line, but you will need to do some research on the rest of what you're trying to do and come back when you have a *specific* question:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"The command line arguments entered are: {string.Join(" ", args)}");

    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
        var filePath = args[0];

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The specified file was not found: {filePath}");
        }
        else
        {
            // Process the file here
            var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Error: Enter the full path to a file as the first command line argument");
    }


    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```